# How do you expose a viewmodel from a different module to a controller in another module?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, unity-container, prism

I have a StockModule and a PurchaseModule. When I receive a new purchase, I add that to the Stock Model in the database.

My problem is that I have an ObservableCollection stockList in the ViewModel in my StockModule and the controller that adds the stock is in the PurchaseModule. I don't know how I'm supposed to tell the ViewVodel in the StockModule that I have updated the stockList already.

I am using databinding in wpf and prism with unity. Updating the view within a module is easy enough but I haven't found a way to do it between two modules.

Should I pass a reference to the StockController when I initialize my PurchaseModule? I don't want to do that because that seems too tightly coupled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use something like Marlon's `Mediator`, or `EventAggregator` from Prism to achieve communication between ViewModels or components (they can be in a single module, or across multiple modules).

In your case, your ViewModel in `PurchaseModule` would publish a message (say, `StockAdded`) via Mediator/EventAggregator, and then your ViewModel from `StockModule` will listen for this message and updates its data and in-effect the view as well.

More reading on Mediator: http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2009/04/16/mediator-v2-for-mvvm-wpf-and-silverlight-applications/

Prism EventAggregator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx

Comment: I already use the EventAggregator from Prism but didn't think to use it in between modules. D'oh! I'll try this now.

Comment: It works like a charm. That was stupid of me. Thanks!